# Heroku cli give an error on login

Tags: heroku

I'am install heroku cli and it show me error on login

```
fork/exec /home/evgeny/.local/share/heroku/cli/lib/node: no such file or directory
```

Is there any way to fix it?

OS: Fedora 25

Comment: install missing `node` package

Comment: @alexus No, node is installed